# Field lines of two charges whose algebraic sum is not zero

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

I know that field lines are directly proportional to the value of electric charge. Assuming that $8$ lines of force, or of field, of the come out of the charge $+q$, then $16$ lines of force will come out of the charge $+2q$ since from the electrostatic field flux $\Phi_S(E)$ we have:

$$\Phi_S(E)\propto (+q)$$

where $S$ it is the Gaussian surface.

In a Physics textbook for students of a high school that does not introduce *the flow of an electrostatic field* and the subsequent concepts, there are some pictures of an electric dipole, a system formed by two equal and opposite charges, $+q$ and $-q$, separated by a non-zero distance. It is observed that if the algebraic **sum of the charges is zero**, and part of the lines of force extend to infinity and part, clearly, are the lines of force that start from the positive charge and close on the negative charge.

[image]

In the case of two positive and negative charges, the drawing that represented the lines of force is clear, but **I observed that the algebraic sum of the charges is not zero**.

[image]

> Is there a rigorous mathematical proof of the reason that two charges of sign $+2q$ and $-q$, although not having algebraic sum zero, do not have field lines extending infinitely from charge $-q$ but the field lines are all closed relative to charge $-q$ starting from $+2q$? By drawing the electrostatic field with a test charge $+q_0$, the field lines are all close in $-q$.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is there a rigorous mathematical proof of the reason that . . . . .*

I cannot give you a rigorous mathematical proof but can give you an indication of what the electric field looks like far away from the charges.

The electric field would be practically indistinguishable from the the electric field due to a single charge $+q$.
The electric field lines would be radial and pointing outwards from the vicinity of the two charges.

[image]

The electric field diagram is misleading it does not show that there is a neutral (zero field) point $(1+\sqrt 2)d$ to the right of the $-q$ charge. $d$ is the separation of the charges.
Beyond the neutral point the electric field line is pointing away from the charges  (to the right).

To find where the neutral point, $N$, is consider the following diagram.

[image]

At the neutral point the electric fields due to the two charges are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

$\vec E_{\rm +2q} + \vec E_{\rm -q} = \vec 0 \Rightarrow k\dfrac {+2q}{(d+x)^2} \hat i + k\dfrac {-q}{x^2} \hat i = \vec 0 \Rightarrow \dfrac {2}{(d+x)^2} = \dfrac {1}{x^2} \Rightarrow x = (1+\sqrt 2)d$

---

I have produced a better set of diagrams to illustrates the points that I have made in my answer.  Note the charge of scale from diagram to diagram.

[image]

Comment: I have upvoted your old question recently. i have not understood competely tour answer. Please can you improved step by step better tour answer please? With the maths formula i decrease the gap of My low level english language.thank you very much.

Comment: What is your first language? Have you tried to use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/)?

Comment: My first language it is the Italian. I have used instead DeepL translate but I received a answer that I cannot code as some aspects of your answer are not clear to me. Excuse me for my sincerity $\ddot\frown$. *The field lines would look like when at a distance much, much greater than the separation between the charges.* If $d$ it is the distance between $+2q$ and $-q$, I think that I will see a situation similar to the first image.

Comment: I think that my reasoning is similar to your part *They would be practically indistinguishable from the the field lines due to a single charge +q, i.e. you would expect to be "observing" field lines radiating outwards from the two charges which at large distance "look" like one charge.* Why the field diagram is misleading as there is a neutral (zero field) point $(1+2\sqrt d)$ to the right of the $-q$ charge, where d is the separation of the charges, and so beyond that the field line is pointing away from the charges? Where you take this consideration and  $(1+2\sqrt d)$?

Comment: With such kindness could you add more details to your answer, as simple as possible? I thank you in advance.

Comment: In the meantime, many thanks again for your patience with me. Now I have understood what you wanted to say. $\ddot\smile$. I am doing this kind of exercise with my students. You did the calculations in your head and I didn't think your answer referred to the computation of the electric field on a charge outside the electric field. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have added four electric field diagrams to illustrate the points that I made in my answer.

Comment: I thank you very very much for your precious contribute to improve my knowledges.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\bl>}
\newcommand{\les}{\bl<}
\newcommand{\greq}{\bl\ge}
\newcommand{\leseq}{\bl\le}
\newcommand{\il}[1]{$\:#1\:$}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\blr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\vlr}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\lara}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lav}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}
\newcommand{\vra}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavra}[2]{\left\langle#1|#2\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\lavvra}[3]{\left\langle#1\right|#2\left|#3\right\rangle}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\Vp}[1]{\vphantom{#1}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$

$\texttt{C O N T E N T S}$

$\texttt{Abstract}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ A. The general case}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ B. Two opposite point electric charges with unequal absolute values}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ C. Two opposite point electric charges with equal absolute values}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ D. Two equal point electric charges}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ E. Two point electric charges of the same sign and unequal values}$

$\bl\S\texttt{ F. Equipotential lines (surfaces)}$

$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

**Abstract**

The differential equation obeyed by the electric field lines between two point electric charges $\:q_{\texttt A},q_{\texttt B}\:$ in general is produced. By the solution a set of parametric equations is provided. At first the solution is applied on the special case of the post $\:\plr{q_{\texttt A},q_{\texttt B}}\e \plr{\m q, \p 2q}\:$ and the relevant diagram is created. It is found to be in agreement with diagrams we meet in many textbooks and the Web. Moreover diagrams for other special cases, like $\:\plr{q_{\texttt A},q_{\texttt B}}\e \plr{ q, q}\:$ or $\:\plr{q_{\texttt A},q_{\texttt B}}\e \plr{q, 3q}\:$, are created.

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **A. The general case**

Two point electric charges $\:q_{\texttt A},q_{\texttt B}\:$ are standing still  on the $\:\mr x\m$axis of a system $\:\mr{Oxyz}\:$ by a distance $\:2a\:$ apart, see [Figure-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeEXD.png). By the presence of these charges we have a 3-dimensional electrostatic field at every point $\:\texttt P\plr{x,y,z}\:$ represented by the electric field intensity vector $\:\mb E\plr{x,y,z}$. An electric field line is a 3-dimensional curve with the vector $\:\mb E\plr{x,y,z}\:$ tangent to it at every one of its points. Because of the rotational symmetry around the $\:\mr x\m$axis the problem is 2-dimensional, so we will work on the problem in the plane $\:\mr{xy}$.

Suppose that an electric field line is a plane curve with regular parametric representation
\begin{equation}
\mb r\plr{t} \e \plr{\!\!\!\plr{x\plr{t},y\plr{t}\Vp{A^B_C}}\!\!\!}  
\tl{A-01}
\end{equation}
the variable $\:t\:$ being the parameter of the representation. A vector tangent to it at a point $\:\texttt P\plr{x,y}\:$ is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr d\mb r}{\mr dt}\e \plr{\dfrac{\mr dx}{\mr dt},\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dt}\Vp{A^B_C}}  
\tl{A-02}
\end{equation}
Since the electric field intensity vector $\:\mb E\plr{x,y}\e\plr{\!\!\!\plr{E_x\plr{x,y},E_y\plr{x,y}\Vp{A^B_C}}\!\!\!} $
is tangent to the curve at this point $\:\texttt P\plr{x,y}\:$ we must have, see [Figure-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnLA.png)
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy/\mr dt}{\mr dx/\mr dt}\e\dfrac{E_y\plr{x,y}}{E_x\plr{x,y}}
\tl{A-03}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{E_y\plr{x,y}}{E_x\plr{x,y}}
\tl{A-04}
\end{equation}

It was proved a posteriori that it would be difficult or may be impossible to succeed separation of the used variables $\:\plr{x,y}\:$ in order to have a solution of this differential equation. This equation was solved by an accidentally successful change of variables. The new variables are
\begin{equation}
u \e \tan\theta_{\mr A} \,,\qquad v \e \tan\theta_{\mr B}\qquad \text{with} \quad \theta_{\mr A},\theta_{\mr B}\bl\in \blr{0,2\pi}
\tl{A-05}
\end{equation}
where $\:\plr{\theta_{\mr A},\theta_{\mr B}}\:$ the angles shown in [Figure-01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeEXD.png) or [Figure-02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnLA.png).
Using the geometry of the problem we'll transform the differential equation \eqref{A-04} with respect to $\:\plr{x,y}\:$ to a differential equation  with respect to $\:\plr{ u, v}$.
At first we have
\begin{equation}
\plr{x \m a}\tan\theta_{\mr B} \e y \e \plr{x \p a}\tan\theta_{\mr A}
\nonumber
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\plr{x \m a} v \e y \e \plr{x \p a} u
\tl{A-06}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
x \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\p\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\m\tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a \,,\qquad y \e \dfrac{2\tan\theta_{\mr B} \tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B} \m \tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a
\tl{A-07}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
x \e \plr{\dfrac{v\p u}{v\m u}} a \,,\qquad y \e \plr{\dfrac{2\,v\, u}{v \m u}} a
\tl{A-08}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{A-08}
\begin{equation}
\mr dx \e 2\,\dfrac{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}{\plr{v\m u}^2}\, a \,,\qquad \mr dy \e 2\,\dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{\plr{v\m u}^2}\, a
\tl{A-09}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{A-09} the left hand side of \eqref{A-04} is transformed as follows
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mr dy}{\mr dx} \e \dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}
\tl{A-10}
\end{equation}
For the transformation of the right hand side of \eqref{A-04} we have at first
\begin{align}
E_x & \e k\plr{q_{\mr A}\dfrac{x \p a}{\vlr{\mr{PA}}^3}\p q_{\mr B}\dfrac{x \m a}{\vlr{\mr{PB}}^3}}
\tl{A-11a}\\
E_y & \e k\plr{q_{\mr A}\dfrac{y}{\,\vlr{\mr{PA}}^3}\p q_{\mr B}\dfrac{y}{\,\vlr{\mr{PB}}^3}\Vp{\dfrac{x \p a}{\mr{PA}^3}}}
\tl{A-11b}
\end{align}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{E_y}{E_x} \e \dfrac{\plr{\dfrac{q_{\mr A}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PA}}^3}\p \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PB}}^3}\Vp{\dfrac{x \p a}{\mr{PA}^3}}}y}{\plr{\dfrac{q_{\mr A}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PA}}^3}\p \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PB}}^3}\Vp{\dfrac{x \p a}{\mr{PA}^3}}}x\p \plr{\dfrac{q_{\mr A}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PA}}^3}\m \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{\,\vlr{\mr{PB}}^3}\Vp{\dfrac{x \p a}{\mr{PA}^3}}}a}
\tl{A-12}
\end{equation}
From the geometry of the problem
\begin{equation}
\vlr{\mr{PA}} \e \dfrac{y}{\sin\theta_{\mr A}} \,,\qquad \vlr{\mr{PB}} \e \dfrac{y}{\sin\theta_{\mr B}}
\tl{A-13}
\end{equation}
and \eqref{A-12} yields
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{E_y}{E_x} \e \dfrac{\plr{q_{\mr A}\sin^3\theta_{\mr A} \p q_{\mr B}\sin^3\theta_{\mr B}}y}{\plr{q_{\mr A}\sin^3\theta_{\mr A} \p q_{\mr B}\sin^3\theta_{\mr B}}x \p \plr{q_{\mr A}\sin^3\theta_{\mr A} \m q_{\mr B}\sin^3\theta_{\mr B}}a}
\tl{A-14}
\end{equation}
Replacing $\:x,y\:$ by their expressions \eqref{A-07} in terms of
$\:\tan\theta_{\mr A},\tan\theta_{\mr B}\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{E_y}{E_x} \e \dfrac{q_{\mr A}\sin^3\theta_{\mr A} \p q_{\mr B}\sin^3\theta_{\mr B}}{  q_{\mr A}\sin^2\theta_{\mr A}\cos\theta_{\mr A}\p q_{\mr B}\sin^2\theta_{\mr B}\cos\theta_{\mr B}}
\tl{A-15}
\end{equation}
Expressing the trigonometric functions $\:\sin\theta_{\mr A},\cos\theta_{\mr A}\:$ and  $\:\sin\theta_{\mr B},\cos\theta_{\mr B}\:$ in terms of the new variables $\:\tan\theta_{\mr A} \e u\:$ and $\:\tan\theta_{\mr B} \e v\:$ respectively, that is
\begin{align}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sin\theta_{\mr A} & \e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\sqrt{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}}\e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}u}{\sqrt{1\p u^2}}\,, \quad \cos\theta_{\mr A} \e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}}{\sqrt{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr A}}}\e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}}{\sqrt{1\p u^2}}
\tl{A-16a}\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!&\nonumber\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sin\theta_{\mr B} & \e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr B}\tan\theta_{\mr B}}{\sqrt{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}}\e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr B}v}{\sqrt{1\p v^2}}\,, \quad \cos\theta_{\mr B} \e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr B}}{\sqrt{1\p\tan^2\theta_{\mr B}}}\e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr B}}{\sqrt{1\p v^2}}
\tl{A-16b}\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!&\nonumber\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\varepsilon_{\mr A} & \e 
\left.
\begin{cases}
\p 1, \quad \texttt{if } \theta_{\mr A}\bl\in \blr{0,\pi/2}\\
\m 1, \quad \texttt{if } \theta_{\mr A}\bl\in \blr{\pi/2, \pi} 
\end{cases}
\right\}\,,\quad 
\varepsilon_{\mr B} \e 
\left.
\begin{cases}
\p 1, \quad \texttt{if } \theta_{\mr B}\bl\in \blr{0,\pi/2}\\
\m 1, \quad \texttt{if } \theta_{\mr B}\bl\in \blr{\pi/2, \pi} 
\end{cases}
\right\}
\tl{A-16c}
\end{align}
equation \eqref{A-15} yields
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{E_y}{E_x} \e \dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32 u^3\p\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32 v^3}{\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32 u^2\p\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32 v^2}
\tl{A-17}
\end{equation}
Combining \eqref{A-04}, \eqref{A-10} and \eqref{A-17} we have the differential equation in terms of the new variables $\:u,v$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{v^2\mr du\m u^2\mr d v}{v\mr du\m u\mr d v}\e\dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32 u^3\p\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32 v^3}{\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32 u^2\p\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32 v^2}
\tl{A-18}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\dfrac{u\,\mr du}{\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32} \e \m\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\dfrac{v\,\mr dv}{\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32} 
\tl{A-19}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon_{\mr A}q_{\mr A}\dfrac{\mr d\plr{1\p u^2}}{\plr{1\p u^2}^\frac32} \e \m\varepsilon_{\mr B}q_{\mr B}\dfrac{\mr d\plr{1\p v^2}}{\plr{1\p v^2}^\frac32}
\tl{A-20}
\end{equation}
which integrated gives the solution
\begin{equation}
q_{\mr A}\dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr A}}{\sqrt{1\p u^2}} \e \m q_{\mr B}\dfrac{\varepsilon_{\mr B}}{\sqrt{1\p v^2}}\p \texttt{constant}
\tl{A-21}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
q_{\mr A}\cos\theta_{\mr A} \p q_{\mr B}\cos\theta_{\mr B} \e \texttt{constant}
\tl{A-22}
\end{equation}
We express this equation in the form
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\cos\theta_{\mr A} \p \lambda_q\cos\theta_{\mr B} \e \mr k \e \text{constant}\:\:\Vp{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\dfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tl{A-23a}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\: \lambda_q \stackrel{\mr{def}}{\bl\equiv} \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}}\e \text{ratio of the electric charges}\:\:\vp}
\tl{A-23b}
\end{equation}

Anyone of the electric field lines is created by \eqref{A-23a} for some constant $\:\mr k$. But not any arbitrary $\:\mr k\:$ corresponds to an
electric field line. From \eqref{A-23a}
\begin{equation}
\mr {k_{max}} \e 1\p \vlr{\lambda_q} \e 1\p \vlr{\dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}}}\,,\qquad \mr {k_{min}} \e \m 1\m \vlr{\lambda_q} \e \m 1\m \vlr{\dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}}}
\tl{A-24}
\end{equation}
so the entire electric field lines family is created from \eqref{A-23a} with
\begin{equation}
\mr k \bl\in \blr{\m\plr{1\p \vlr{\lambda_q}},\plr{1\p \vlr{\lambda_q}}\vp}\,, \qquad \lambda_q \e \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}}
\tl{A-25}
\end{equation}
To find the parametric equations of the $\:\mr k\m$electric field line we use equations \eqref{A-07}
\begin{align}
x  & \e \dfrac{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\p\tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B}\m\tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a
\tl{A-26a}\\
y & \e \dfrac{2\tan\theta_{\mr B} \tan\theta_{\mr A}}{\tan\theta_{\mr B} \m \tan\theta_{\mr A}}\, a
\tl{A-26b}
\end{align}
From \eqref{A-23a}
\begin{equation}
\theta_{\mr A} \e\arccos\plr{\mr k \m \lambda_q\cos\theta_{\mr B}}
\tl{A-27}
\end{equation}
so the $\:{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}\m$parametric equations for the $\:{\color{blue}{\mr k}}\m$electric field line are
\begin{align}
x_{\color{blue}{\mr k}}\plr{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}  & \e \dfrac{\tan{\color{red}{\bl{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}}}\p\tan\blr{\arccos\plr{{\color{blue}{\mr k}} \m \lambda_q\cos{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}\vp}}{\tan{\color{red}{\bl{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}}}\m\tan\blr{\arccos\plr{{\color{blue}{\mr k}} \m \lambda_q\cos{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}\vp}}\, a
\tl{A-28a}\\
y_{\color{blue}{\mr k}}\plr{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}} & \e \dfrac{2\tan{\color{red}{\bl{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}}}\tan\blr{\arccos\plr{{\color{blue}{\mr k}} \m \lambda_q\cos{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}\vp}}{\tan{\color{red}{\bl{{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}}}\m\tan\blr{\arccos\plr{{\color{blue}{\mr k}} \m \lambda_q\cos{\color{red}{\bl{\theta_{\mr B}}}}}\vp}}\, a
\tl{A-28b}\\
{\color{blue}{\mr k}} &\bl\in \blr{\m\plr{1\p \vlr{\lambda_q}},\plr{1\p \vlr{\lambda_q}}\vp}\,, \qquad \lambda_q \e \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}}
\tl{A-28c}
\end{align}
Note that a $\:{\color{blue}{\mr k}}\m$electric field line created by equation \eqref{A-23a} is symmetric with respect to the $\:\mr x\m$axis since if $\:\theta_{\mr A}\:$ and $\:\theta_{\mr B}\:$ satisfy this equation then   $\:\theta'_{\mr A}\e 2\pi\m \theta_{\mr A}\:$ and $\:\theta'_{\mr B}\e 2\pi\m \theta_{\mr B}\:$ satisfy it also. This 2-dimensional $\:\mr x\m$mirror symmetry is due to the 3-dimensional rotational symmetry around the $\:\mr x\m$axis.

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **B. Two opposite point electric charges with unequal absolute values**

This case corresponds to negative values of the ratio of charges, $\:\lambda_q\les 0\:$, except the value $\:\lambda_q \bl\ne \m 1\:$, that is

\begin{equation}
\lambda_q \e \dfrac{q_{\mr B}}{q_{\mr A}} \bl\in \plr{\m\infty,\m 1} \bl\cup \plr{\m 1,0}
\tl{B-01}
\end{equation}
The range $\:\plr{\m 1,0}\:$ in \eqref{B-01} could be omitted since a case with $\:\lambda_q \bl\in\plr{\m 1,0}\:$ would be considered as case $\:\lambda'_q \e \lambda^{\m 1}_q\bl\in\plr{\m\infty,\m 1}$. Also, for the case $\:\lambda_q \e \m 1\:$ we refer to $\bl\S$ **C**.

[image]

In [Figure-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KAE.png) we have a diagram of the electric field lines for the value $\:\lambda_q\e \m 2$. We'll explain point to point all about the details and numerical values. So according to \eqref{A-25} for the  variable $\:\mr k\:$ we have
\begin{equation}
\m 3\leseq\mr k\leseq \p 3
\tl{B-02}
\end{equation}
For these values the $\:\mr k\m$electric field lines are created as follows :
\begin{equation}
\nonumber
\end{equation}

1. $\:\plr{\m 3\leseq\mr k\les \m 1}\:$ Electric field lines joining the two charges in the upper half of the plane.
2. $\:\plr{\mr k \e \m 1}\:$ Electric field line with semicircular-like part and straight segment part on the $\:\mr x\m$axis joining the two charges in the upper half of the plane. The semicircular-like part and the straight segment part on the $\:\mr x\m$axis meet at the neutral point $\:\mr{NP}\:$ where  $\:\mb E \e \bl 0$. At the neutral point $\:\mr{NP}\:$ we have a discontinuity of the direction of the line tangent to the electric field curve.
3. $\:\plr{\m 1\les\mr k\les\p 1}\:$ All electric field lines from the positive point charge $\:q_{\mr B}\e \p 2q\:$ to infinity. Especially for $\:\mr k\e 0\:$ the created electric field line moves away to infinity asymptotically to a straight line parallel to $\:\mr y\m$axis which intersects the $\:\mr x\m$axis at point $\:\mr C$. Although we have not a proof it seems that this point is the $^{\prime\prime}$$\textit{electric charge center}$ $^{\prime\prime}$. With reference to [Figure-04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Rdn.png) we must have
   \begin{equation}
   x_{\texttt C}\e\dfrac{q_{\texttt A}x_{\texttt A}\p q_{\texttt B}x_{\texttt B}}{q_{\texttt A}\p q_{\texttt B}}
   \tl{B-03}
   \end{equation}
   which applied to [Figure-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KAE.png) gives
   \begin{equation}
   x_{\texttt C}\e\dfrac{\plr{\m q}\plr{\m a}\p \plr{\p 2q}\plr{\p a}}{\plr{\m q}\p \plr{\p 2q}}\e 3\cdot a \e 3\cdot 2  \e 6
   \tl{B-04}
   \end{equation}
4. $\:\plr{\mr k \e \p 1}\:$ Electric field line with semicircular-like part and straight segment part on the $\:\mr x\m$axis joining the two charges in the loewer half of the plane. The semicircular-like part and the straight segment part on the $\:\mr x\m$axis meet at the neutral point $\:\mr{NP}\:$ where  $\:\mb E \e \bl 0$. At the neutral point $\:\mr{NP}\:$ we have a discontinuity of the direction of the line tangent to the electric field curve.
5. $\:\plr{\p 1\les\mr k\leseq \p 3}\:$ Electric field lines joining the two charges in the lower half of the plane.
   \begin{equation}
   \nonumber
   \end{equation}

Note that electric field lines joining the two charges are trapped inside the circular-like region (spherical-like in 3 dimensions) while the electric field lines from the positive point charge $\:q_{\mr B}\e \p 2q\:$ to infinity run outside of this circular-like region.

[Figure-04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Rdn.png) is identical to [Figure-03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KAE.png) but with formulas on the basis of which the numerical values of the latter are derived.

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **C. Two opposite point electric charges with equal absolute values**

For this case, where $\:\lambda_q \e \m 1$, see my answer here : [Equation describing the electric field lines of opposite charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/774449/equation-describing-the-electric-field-lines-of-opposite-charges/775101#775101).

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **D. Two equal point electric charges**

For this case,  where $\:\lambda_q \e \p 1$, a typical diagram is shown in [Figure-05](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NCgv.png).

[image]

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **E. Two point electric charges of the same sign and unequal values**

For this case,  where $\:\lambda_q \gr\p 1$, a typical diagram is shown in [Figure-06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpM2I.png). Note that a field line from the absolutely larger charge moves away to infinity asymptotically to a straight line parallel to $\:\mr y\m$axis which intersects $\:\mr x\m$axis at point $\:\mr C$. It seems that this point is the $^{\prime\prime}$$\textit{electric charge center}$ $^{\prime\prime}$. With reference to [Figure-06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpM2I.png) we must have
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\vlr{\texttt{CA}}}{\vlr{\texttt{CB}}} \e \dfrac{3q}{q}\e 3
\tl{E-01}
\end{equation}

[image]

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

$\bl\S$ **F. Equipotential lines (surfaces)**

[image]
[Electric field lines versus equipotential surfaces](https://youtu.be/9IVcLw91NXs) (video).

$\bl{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-}$

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Watch the production of this image here :
[Electric field lines of two unequal opposite charges](https://youtu.be/3xwNHZNiono) (Video)

---

[image]

---

[image]
Reference for above Figure : [Angle of electrostatic field lines through an equilibrium point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744172/angle-of-electrostatic-field-lines-through-an-equilibrium-point?noredirect=1&lq=1), see &Vincent Fraticelli's answer.

---

Comment: I am so happy that you gave me an answer. I ask you to view some of my recent questions when you can, and I am equally happy to receive your answers. You are among my favorite users because your way of reasoning is purely with formulas and I, not being a native speaker, understand better. +1

Answer (score 1):

To add to the good answer by @Farcher,

- Imagine walking along the x-axis from large positive-x to toward the negative charge $-q$ near the origin. You see what appears to be an "apparent point charge $+q$", so the electric field at your location is pointing radially away toward the positive-x direction, and seems to have an inverse-square dependence from the apparent point-charge.
- Suppose instead, you were extremely close, just to the right of the negative charge. The electric field at your location would be directed toward the negative-x direction since the field at your location is dominated by the nearby negative charge $-q$.
- Somewhere between large positive-x and just-to-the-right of the negative charge, the electric field must have been zero.
  In fact, as you approach from large positive-x, you begin to observe that the electric field is no longer inverse-square. You may be able to deduce that the "apparent point charge" is not a point charge... but a distribution of charges.
  At one point on the x-axis, you will find a location where the electric field is zero, due to the superposition of the electric fields of the $+2q$ charge and of the $-q$ charge, separated by a displacement $\vec d$. You can calculate this value of $x$, where $x>d$.

See my Desmos plot of the situation
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/of7docjwsv

Note: the x-components of the electric force are being plotted (not the magnitude of the force).

(You can zoom in at the location of the target charge Q to
see the behavior of the electric field near it.)

[image: robphy-desmos-electric-force]

Comment: I add my upvoted $\ddot \smile$. Peraphs with a drawing with the formulas I understand better.

Comment: @Sebastiano I added a Desmos plot

Comment: Thank you very much and I return your kindness. Thank you again.